# C++ How to Extract Substring between two same symbols

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to c++ programming. I need some help,

I have string : 
---- Input : "Name : $$ Enter Your Name2 $$"
I want to extract string between $$ symbols including symbols : 
---- Output : "$$ Enter Your Name2 $$"

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please show the code that you already have, and explain what exactly is the problem you can't yet solve in that code.

Comment: [The standard regular expression library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) might be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are very useful in this case.

*C++11* has [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) library.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::string parse_string(const std::string& str) {
  static const std::string REGEX_STR = R"__(\$\$(\w|\W)*\$\$)__";
  std::regex regex(REGEX_STR);
  std::smatch regex_iterator;
  if (std::regex_search(str, regex_iterator, regex)) {
    return regex_iterator.str();
  }
  return std::string("");
}
```

The code can be improved but it should represent a good starting point. Specific case should be handled, for example: more `$$*$$` in a string, etc...

---

**Note:**
`R"__(\$\$(\w|\W)*\$\$)__";` is a [raw string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in order to make more readable the regex.

Answer (score -1):

Just search the string for the delimiter:

```
std::string parse_string(const std::string& str, const std::string& delim) {
    auto start = str.find(delim);
    if (start == std::string::npos)
        return "";
    auto end = str.find(delim, start + delim.size());
    if (end == std::string::npos)
        return str.substr(start);
    else
        return str.substr(start, end - start + delim.size);
}
```